# Urlize DRF Link

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datatables, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF serializer:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    link = serializers.CharField(source='get_analytic_link', allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['link',]
```

In the browsable API, the links are clickable. However, when they are served up to a DataTable via a JSON endpoint, they are (predictably) not clickable. In plain Django, I would do something like this:

```
<td>{{ activity.get_analytic_link|urlize }}</td>
```

How could I replicate that behavior in DRF so that links are clickable?

Comment: I have no experience with datatables, but shouldn't you just wrap the url in an <a> tag?

Comment: at which step in the process would that be included? if I add that into the JSON payload, I would think it would just show up as a string in the browser, <a> tags and all.

Comment: I think you should not change anything on the API, just keep sending the url, and handle this on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this a job on the frontend, and you should use DataTable's [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) feature.

Example:

```
var responseObj = [
    { "information": "A1", "weblink": "http://www.microsoft.com" },
    { "information": "A2", "weblink": "http://www.yahoo.com" },
    { "information": "A3", "weblink": "http://www.google.com" },
    { "information": "A4", "weblink": "http://www.duckduckgo.com" }
];

$('#example').dataTable({
   "data": responseObj,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "information" }, 
      { 
         "data": "weblink",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }

            return data;
         }
      } 
   ]
});
```